# django server error (500) when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, heroku, production, http-status-code-500

This is `base.py` file

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


SECRET_KEY = 'h@1l- Holla!!! this is something crazy, $2423$#@$#@E@e#R3\e['

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # typical django code...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # typical django code...
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    # typical django code...
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    # typical django code...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Static settings
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]


# Media settings
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

This is `production.py`

```py
from .base import *

import environ
import django_heroku

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
)

SECRET_KEY = 'lol'

# right now for convenience I've hard-coded these
# despite having environ package
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MIDDLEWARE.insert(1, 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')

DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 60

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I've renamed the original `settings.py` to `base.py`, and extended it to `production.py`. And also updated `manage.py`, `wsgi.py` and `asgi.py`.
Basically following this approach -> https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html

Everything looks just fine to me

[image]

This code is giving **Server Error (500)**.
The problem is **not** in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, that's for sure.

**EDIT:** few errors get fixed when I removed this line **`django_heroku.settings(locals())`**, though media files were still not loaded

Many people are facing the same problem and didn't get an appropriate answer yet!

Please help me with an answer with an explanation.

**EDIT 2:**

```
[08/Sep/2021 22:01:05] ERROR [django.request:224] Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 147, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 126, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\.virtualenvs\project-nE60Z89-\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 417, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'home/css/base.css'
[08/Sep/2021 22:01:05] ERROR [django.server:161] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145
[08/Sep/2021 22:01:05] WARNING [django.request:224] Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Sep/2021 22:01:05] WARNING [django.server:161] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Comment: Does it not receive an error when you set the `DEBUG` to `True`?
Check to see what error occurs with this mode

Comment: If you're in debug mode, you should have a traceback in your browser or on your server program.

Comment: @HamidrezaKhorammfar No, it didn't receive any error when `DEBUG` is `True`.

Comment: @ClémentPéau That's the whole problem, no error or traceback is occurring, just request error 500 is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can log all errors to file with the below and it will log even when `DEBUG=False`

---

Update: Try this.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[contactor] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        # Send all messages to console
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        # Send info messages to syslog
        'syslog':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'facility': SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL2,
            'address': '/dev/log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        # Warning messages are sent to admin emails
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        },
        # critical errors are logged to sentry
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # This is the "catch all" logger
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'syslog', 'mail_admins', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I got this error in the log file - `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'home/css/base.css'` ...

Comment: please help, with the above `ValueError`, I searched the entire internet but no solutions were found

Comment: so give me full traceback

Comment: see the EDIT in the question, maybe that'll help

Comment: given as **EDIT 2**, please check

Comment: The main problem that gave you error 500 was solved. In this case, this is the same problem that caused the 500 error, and due to the error, if the error is from your files, you should check the file, probably a typing problem in blocking. (in `'home/css/base.css'`)

Comment: I request you to read **EDIT:**, after removing `django_heroku.settings(local())` it works, but media files still don't works.

Comment: change that line to `django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)`  Then run `python manage.py collectstatic` from the heroku shell